# python3 split big file by delimiter into small files (not size, lines)

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

Newbie here. Ultimate mission is to learn how to take two big yaml files and split them into several hundred small files. I haven't yet figured out how to use the ID # as the filename, so one thing at a time.

First: split the big files into many. Here's a tiny bit of my test data file test-file.yml. Each post has a - delimiter on a line by itself:

```
-
    ID: 627
    more_post_meta_data_and_content
-
    ID: 628
```

And here's my code that isn't working. So far I don't see why:

```
with open('test-file.yml', 'r') as myfile:
    start = 0
    cntr = 1
    holding = ''
    for i in myfile.read().split('\n'):
        if (i == '-\n'):
            if start==1:
                with open(str(cntr) + '.md','w') as opfile:
                    opfile.write(op)
                    opfile.close()
                    holding=''
                    cntr += 1
            else:
                start=1
        else:
            if holding =='':
                holding = i
            else:
                holding = holding + '\n' + i
    myfile.close()
```

All hints, suggestions, pointers welcome. Thanks.

Comment: since the file was split by '\n', I would say 'i=='-\n' should not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the entire file into memory and then splitting the memory regions is very inefficient if the input files are large.  Try this instead:

```
with open('test-file.yml', 'r') as myfile:
    opfile = None
    cntr = 1
    for line in myfile:
        if line == '-\n':
            if opfile is not None:
                opfile.close()
            opfile = open('{0}.md'.format(cntr),'w')
            cntr += 1
        opfile.write(line)
    opfile.close()
```

Notice also, you don't `close` things you have opened in a `with` context manager; the very purpose of the context manager is to take care of this for you.

Comment: Thanks to all. This was a great learning moment, and d'oh, forgot to put the initial op definition at the start. @tripleee what's the {0} placeholder in line 8?

Comment: It's used by `format` and gets replaced with the first argument. Equivalently `open('%s.md' % cntr)` using old-style format strings, or `open(f'{cntr}.md')` using a modern `f`-string. It's all in the Python 101 materials.

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie myself, at first glance your trying to write an undeclared variable op to your output. You were nearly spot on, just need to iterate through your opfile and write the contents:

```
    with open('test-file.yml', 'r') as myfile:
        start = 0
        cntr = 1
        holding = ''
        for i in myfile.read().split('\n'):
            if (i == '-\n'):
                if start==1:
                    with open(str(cntr) + '.md','w') as opfile:
                        for line in opfile:
                            op = line
                            opfile.write(op)
                            opfile.close()
                            holding=''
                            cntr += 1
                else:
                    start=1
            else:
                if holding =='':
                    holding = i
                else:
                    holding = holding + '\n' + i
        myfile.close()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you are working in a `with context` on an open file, the `with` will automatically take care of closing it for you when you exit this block. So you don't need `file.close()` anywhere.

There is a function called `readlines` that outputs a generator that reads a line from an open file one line at a time. That will work much more efficiently than `read()` followed by a `split()`. Think about it. You are loading a massive file in memory, and then asking CPU to split that ginormous text by `\n` character. Not very efficient.

You wrote `opfile.write(op)`. Where is this `op` defined? Don't you want to write the content in `holding` that you've defined?

Try the following.

```
with open('test.data', 'r') as myfile:
    counter = 1
    content = ""
    start = True

    for line in myfile.readlines():
        if line == "-\n" and not start:
            with open(str(counter) + '.md', 'w') as opfile:
                opfile.write(content)

            content = ""
            counter += 1
        else:
            if not start:
                content += line

        start = False

    # write the last file if test-file.yml doesn't end with a dash
    if content != "":
        with open(str(counter) + '.md', 'w') as opfile:
            opfile.write(content)
```